# What does this mean "scanf("%[^\n]",buf);" ? What is its equivalent C++ syntax?

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to the C programming language. I have done some programming in C++ and I know that scanf is used to take input and `\n` means next line, but I cannot understand the complete expression.
And what would be the equivalent C++ syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means "read everything until you encounter an end-of-line character, and store the result in the provided `char*` pointer". An equivalent C++ syntax is exactly the same (you need to include `<cstdio>` for that), but in C++ you should prefer a string-based API to `scanf`:

```
string buf;
getline(cin, buf);
```

The reason for this is that `scanf` with the format string that you provided is prone to buffer overruns: if end-user types in more characters than the size of the `buf`, C or C++ will continue writing the data to the memory, causing undefined behavior. You can fix the format string (highly recommended) to limit the input to the size of the buffer, like this:

```
char buf[100];
scanf("%99[^\n]", buf);
```

but now you are limited to strings of 99 characters or less. `std::getline` with a `std::string`, on the other hand, is free from this limitation.